# Excel creation in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml, excel, xsd

Hi I am trying to create Excel file through iOS app which will have some images as well as data.
For this purpose I am creating Xml file through code using OOXML concept, which can be open as Excel. Its working fine with data, but I didn't found any tag for embedding image in xml.

I have converted all images into Base64 string and putted it into XML.Now, Is there any way in XML by which Base64 string will convert into Image while opening as Excel?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Though I've not read OOXML specification, it seems that images are not stored in XML but in `xl/media` directory. And its references are described in `xl/drawings/`. I guess you don't have to convert images to Base64.

Comment: Yes you are right... But due to file size constraint I want to convert images in Base 64 string and put it into Xml which can be open as Excel

Answer (score 0):

I understand your logic by converting all the images into a Base64 string to save space however Excel disables embedded images as a security precaution. Base64 encoding makes it very difficult for anti-virus software to detect a possible threat. Hence the reason Excel has not been made to decode the string back into an image again.

**Do have a look at this link where a person claims to be able to successfully decode and encode Base64 images to the excel file.**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1400028/445312

I hope this helps.

**PK**

Comment: Yes, I have gone through link you provided. In that he has decoded through objective code. I am trying to decode by Excel/Xml it self, means Xml can be opened as Excel on windows machine with decoding Base 64 strings to Images